# Can't start php-cgi.exe - MSVCR110.dll is missing

Tags: windows, php, php-cgi

Trying to setup nginx and php on my Windows machine, but every time I try to start `php-cgi.exe` I get a system error.

> The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the problem to fix this problem.

I'm using Wnmp to start my programs and downloaded the latest PHP 5.5 to it (32bit version).

I have Visual C++ 2008 x86, C++ 2010 x64 and C++ 2010 x86.

What am I missing and why can't PHP list programs required for PHP (cgi) to work?

Comment: How the heck could this be off topic? I'd really like to know. This is a bonafide server issue for me.

Comment: yea that's stupid. this is a real issue and the fix below worked for me

Comment: Perhaps this will be better suited to StackOverflow as it is about programming tools.

Comment: I hate it when the moderators mark stuff as off-topic. I got here via google by typing in an exact phrase. It is not off-topic for me, and it is the only place I found my answer after much searching.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need VS C++ 2012. Go here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

You need to download the x86 version if you install the 64bit version it will give the same error.

Comment: Even if the php version is 5.5.3 and for 64-bit systems ?!

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Yes, it relies on some 32-bit functions.

Comment: I needed both, well I installed the 32bit version first and it failed as per ops error message and then I installed the 64 bit version and all was well. This is on Windows Server 2012 data center using PHP 5.5 (5.5.4)

Comment: All the other pages were suggesting I needed 2010, but finally I came across your answer. Very Thankful! Like rism, I had to install both 32bit and 64bit before it worked.

Comment: Thanks surprised this wasn't included with the WebPlatform PHP installer module.

Comment: FYI the name of the missing file is important. If you are looking for `MSVCR110.dll` then this is the answer. If you are looking for `MSVCR100.dll` (not the version number is 100 instead of 110) then you need to download the `VS C++ 2010` package.